# find a outlier data using standard normal distribution in Java programming

Tags: java, statistics, data-analysis

Hi I want to find a outlier data using standard normal distribution

I'm not used to statistics. So If any error in my question, please give me advice.

I have two requirement.

1. I want to make a standard normal distribution using integer list of data like [15, 13, 18, 20, 22, 17, 16, 16, 30, 18, 15, 16]
2. When a new data is coming to list like 32, I want to check that new data is in range of standard normal distribution with in +- 1 sigma from mean

[image: Std Distribution]

Thanks for reading my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation), the standard deviation `σ` can be computed as:

```
σ = sqrt(E[X^2] - E[X]^2)
```

where `E` is the expected value (mean). The following simple class does just that:

```
class Statistics {

    int count = 0; // num values so far
    double mean = Double.NaN; // E[X]
    double meanOfSquares = Double.NaN; // E[X^2]

    public void add(final double value) {
        if (count == 0) {
            mean = value;
            meanOfSquares = value  * value;
        } else {
            mean = (mean * count + value) / (count + 1);
            meanOfSquares = (meanOfSquares * count + value * value) / (count + 1);
        }
        count++;
    }

    public double getMean() {
        // sum of all values divided by count
        return mean;
    }

    public double getVariance() {
        // σ^2 = E[X^2] - E[X]^2;
        return meanOfSquares - mean * mean;
    }

    public double getStandardDeviation() {
        // variance is square of standard deviance
        return Math.sqrt(getVariance());
    }
}
```

You can now check whether a value `x` is within one `σ` as follows:

```
Statistics statistics = new Statistics(): 
statistics.add(10); 
statistics.add(12); 

int x = 5; 
double mean = statistics.getMean();
double sigma = statistics.getStandardDeviation();
if (x < mean - sigma || x > mean + sigma) {
    System.out.println(x + " not within one standard deviation");
}
```

Comment: I really appreciated your answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm very sorry for this request but can you edit this code to standard normal distribution?

Comment: This code is already based on the normal distribution. The normal distribution `N(μ, σ^2)` is characterised by a mean value `μ` and a variance `σ^2`. The `Statistics` class computes estimates for the two parameters `μ` and `σ^2` from the given data. The code snippet at the end illustrates how one can test whether a new value is within `+/- 1σ` of the mean `μ` of the values observed so far. Note that this only works properly after you've added at least two values to `Statistics`.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I realize that there is no need to standardization of normal distribution.